# How to transfer object server-to-server in a GWT project?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

i'm doing a GWT project for school and i need your help.

I must do a web app, for a car rent agency. Each agency has a database and i need to start two (or more) istances of the same web app: one for each agency.

this picture rappresent perfectly what i'm tryin to explain:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByvS4LX9oVXnd1NtWGFiVXR3ZnM/edit?usp=sharing

So i must transfer object (for example a car) from a database to another database, similar to what I just do "locally" with GWT RPC, but from server to server. How can i do this?

I just done the "local" part of this project, so i can add employeers, clients, cars and start/stop a rent. If can help, I used Hibernate and HSQLDB as database.

I know about syncproxy, but i noticed a small documentation on the web, there are an alternatives?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt recommend a GWT based solution for this. What you need is a replication between your  local and remote database. I dont know the capabilities of the hsqldb, but you also can serialize your objects between the java backends.